# How to configure AWS Elastic cache redis with Magento2

Tags: magento2, redis, aws

To optimize magento2 i have created admin as separate node (ubuntu20)and fronted node(ubuntu20) in AWS. Now im trying to implement Elastic cache redis with magento. I have created Redis in AWS but im bit confused with the approach, can some guide me if the following is right way

1. Install redis cli for ubuntu20 , not sure if its possible to install client only instead of redis server again
2. ​Get the endpoint and update the env as per the link
   https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/redis/redis-session.html
3. verify redis-cli ping

Also how do i create new database in Redis elastic cache in AWS if i want page cache as well?